# How to solve CameraX flickering screen bug

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

before the version 1.0.0-beta03 CameraX I used version 1.0.0-alpha06 and the image analysis along with barcode scanning worked fine for me. Now on the newer version it doesnt always work because the camera preview is sometimes flickering and the images end up being unclear enough to be able to detect barcodes.

Look at the images I attached. The screen is black on purpose to be able to see the difference.
[image: alpha06]
[image: beta03]

I think the problem is with the camera using up too much memory. I noticed that if I clear the apps running in the background and restart the app, the camera quality gets better with no such screen flickering. When I did so once it said "freed 200mb memory" just from my app alone. I cant reproduce the flickering bug all the time, but what I do is kill the app, restart and eventualy it starts flickering. In my **BarcodeScanFragment** here is my onDestroy

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // I call cameraUtil.unbindCamera() which executes code below:
    cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
    cameraExecutor?.shutdown()
}
```

Here is my **CameraUtil** (that I use to initialize camera for different fragments) **setupCameraX** function :

```
fun setupCameraX(previewView: PreviewView,fragment:Fragment, analyzer:ImageAnalysis.Analyzer?) {
        previewView.preferredImplementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.TEXTURE_VIEW
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(fragment.context!!)
        val rotation = previewView.display.rotation
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().setTargetRotation(rotation).build()
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider(null))

            var useCase:UseCase?=null
            if(analyzer==null){
                imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                        .setTargetRotation(previewView.display.rotation)
                        .build()
                useCase = imageCapture!!
            }else{
                val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                        .build()
                        .also{
                            it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor!!, analyzer)
                        }
                useCase = imageAnalysis
            }


            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

            try{
                camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(fragment, cameraSelector, preview,useCase)
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
            }catch(ex: Exception){
                Log.e("error",ex.message,ex)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(fragment.context))
    }
```

I make sure to call

> cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

So that the previous camerax use cases are unbound

**EDIT:** device Huawei P smart 2019

Comment: switching to camerax version 1.0.0-beta05 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was experiencing a flickering only when I pop a fragment from the back stack.

I'm using camera x version 1.0.0-beta05

Finally, I could fix this flickering simply by removing this line

```
previewView.preferredImplementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.TEXTURE_VIEW
```